# How do you make a curve which is in a spiral shape and scale it while keeping one point still

Tags: bezier-curves, scale

I've already made the spiral, but I want to know how to scale it while keeping one end still, like what would happen if you compressed a spring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it by changing the origin point of the object with Control-Alt-C.